# difference between numpy repeat and this method

Tags: python, statistics

I want to generate a random sample size of 90 (10+30+50), create a list that holds these 90 randomly generated samples and find the sample median. this is what I'm given:

```
sub_pop = [300, 500, 1000]
samplesize = [10, 30, 50]
std_list = [40, 50, 60]
mean_list = [50, 60, 70]
```

in other words, I want to randomly generate a sub sample size of 10 from sub_pop 300, a sub sample size of 30 from sub_pop 500 and a sub sample size of 50 from sub_pop 1000 and then append the results into a single list. each sub_pop are normally distributed as follows: sub_pop 300 is normally distributed wif std dev 40 and mean 50, sub_pop 500 is normally distributed wif std dev 50 and mean 60 and so on.

this is what I've done so far:

```
import numpy as np
n_pop = 1800
obs_size = 90
sub_pop = [300, 500, 1000]
samplesize = [10, 30, 50]
std_list = [40, 50, 60]
mean_list = [50, 60, 70]

list = []
for i in range(300):
    list += np.random.normal(loc = 50, scale = 40, size = 10).tolist()

for i in range(500):
    list += np.random.normal(loc = 60, scale = 50, size = 30).tolist()

for i in range(1000):
    list += np.random.normal(loc = 70, scale = 60, size = 50).tolist()

list1 = [abs(x) for x in list]
print(list1)
print(np.median(list1))
```

is my approach right?

Comment: I do not get the notion of pop and sample size you are using. To me it looks like, ok, I want 10 element normally distributed around 50 with a std of 40, then I want 30 ... and so on. What is the sub_pop?

Comment: hi mathieu I'm sorry for not framing my question as clearly as possible. am not too sure on the technicalities as Im pretty new to python and statistics. so wad I have here is a population size of 1800 which contains 3 different sub population size of 300, 500 and 1000. wad I want to do is to sample 90 from this population while ensuring that the proportion in this sample of 90 is proportionate to the population.

Comment: so "samplesize" is the proportion that I should have in each respective sub population in the sample size of 90 that I hard coded.

Comment: Ok, well from what you write, I feel like we do not care about this population size. Taking directly `sample_size` elt with the random parameter of the population is enough. Compare to my answer, it means that the `size` argument must be changed to `size=samplesize[i]`.

Comment: I do not quite get it. would it be possible for u to write it out so I could visualise and understand the code better

Comment: You want a sample (90 elements) from a population of size N with mean X and std S. Why do you care about the size N? Why taking 90 individuals with mean X and std S is not good enough? I believe it is, and it is a representation of your population of size N. Thus, you do not need to bother with the population size. I've edited the code.

Comment: ok I get it! thanks so much

Comment: but wad is the elt function u used? wad does tat do

Comment: To create the element (it's not a function, just the english word element), I used `np.random.normal()` which returns an array of element of the size `size`.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you are trying to do, but instead of

```
for i in range(1000):
    list += np.random.normal(loc = 70, scale = 60, size = 50).tolist()
```

you could use

```
x = np.random.normal(loc = 70, scale = 60, size = (50, 1000))
```

Then the absolute is just

```
x_abs = np.abs(x)
```

And for the correct use of median use the [keyword `axis`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.median.html) to specify which dimension to operate on.

Maybe

```
np.median(x_abs, axis=1)
```

Comment: hi! sorry if I didn't frame the question clearly, am pretty new to the program as well as statistics so I'm not too sure about the technicalities. but what I'm trying to do here is generate random samples from 3 normal distributions, add It all into a list and then find the median

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you want one sample, which contains the population specified.

```
sub_pop = [300, 500, 1000]
samplesize = [10, 30, 50]
std_list = [40, 50, 60]
mean_list = [50, 60, 70]

data=[np.random.normal(loc=mean_list[i], scale=std_list[i], size=samplesize[i]) for i in range(3)]
x = [elt for L in data for elt in L]
```

The code above create a flat list with all the element in it. Then you want the median, so I assume something like this:

```
import statistics
statistics.median(x)
```

Your goal / data is really unclear. Hope you can find a few ideas in the codes we provide.